# HDMI USB-C External Monitor and Mouse

Tags: display, mouse, hdmi, external-display, usb-c

I have a monitor that is connected via (i) HDMI to HDMI cable that goes into a (ii) HDMI to USB-C adapter (so two wires). The USB-C connects to my laptop. Video is transmitted fine.

Audio is connected directly to monitor. Works fine.

I want to charge my laptop via the monitor. In the current setting it does not charge.

I want to connect my USB keyboard and USB mouse to the monitor. If I plug the USB directly in the monitpr, both the mouse and keyboard do not work.

How should I do this?i.e., Charge and/or plus mouse and keyboard to monitor.

SPECS: Laptop Dell XPS 15. Ports available: USB-C, USB, HDMI
Monitor: Acer. Ports available: HDMI, USB (no USB-C), display port, audio.

UPDATE: I now have a HDMI to HDMI cable going from monitor to laptop, respectively. This provides the display. And, I have a DisplayPort to USB cable going from monitor to laptop, respectively. This enables me to use the monitor USB hubs for a mouse/keyboard. So that problem is solved. Only the charging question remains.

Comment: The USB ports you have on the monitor are not connected to the USB ports on the computer through HDMI.  Either the USB ports on the monitor are for viewing media on a USB stick (not likely).. or the USB ports on the monitor are only a convenience to give you a USB hub and have nothing to do with anything else.  You probably need a "USB-C to USB-B Cable".. you should find an input on the back of the monitor for USB-B to know for sure.

Comment: just one thing to add to @SeñorCMasMas : to charge the laptop via the monitor, you would need them to be connected directly via usb-c. Neither hdmi nor usb-b will charge your laptop, only usb-c is able to do that!

Comment: I see. Would a "simple" like a phone cable with USB and USB-C be able to charge my laptop then? 
2. In the past on a  different monitor and with different cables my mouse and keyboard were connected to the monitor and I was also charging the laptop... So I know it works, just don't know how

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas update: I put a basic USB to USB-C from monitor to laptop, respectively. Neither is the display transmitted nor the charging.

Comment: Please tell us both the laptop and monitor make/model.  This would simplify things greatly.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas just updated. Also, I can charge my phone from a USB to USB-C cable from the monitor (but not laptop),

Comment: "Monitor: Acer" is not helpful.  My Acer monitor does not have USB anything on it.  I still need the model.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Acer B7. Model name: B277U

Comment: [This is one of the worst manuals I have ever seen](https://global-download.acer.com/GDFiles/Document/User%20Manual/User%20Manual_Acer_1.0_A_A.pdf?acerid=636614475283122908). No specs on the USB other than "USB CABLE" with a picture too blurry to tell what kind of connector.  It is not expected that you would charge the laptop from the monitor as the monitor's USB power is expected to come FROM the laptop. One would expect you to plug things like mouse, keyboard, and headphones into the monitor (sorta like a docking station).. Sorry I can't help more.  Great Monitor!  Sh*t Manual!

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas as I said the mouse and keyboard are already working via the monitor now. All USB ports on the monitor are functioning. (The solution was to use a Display Port to USB). But I cannot get to charge the laptop via the monitor still.

Comment: The reason that the mouse and keyboard are working is because the laptop is providing a connection (and power) via USB.  How can you power the laptop via USB when the laptop is the source of power on that same USB?

Comment: As I said, in the past this could be done. If I knew the answer to your question I wouldn't post it here. Unfortunately your comments aren't helping :( the mouse issue was solved by me without your help.

Comment: "I want to charge my laptop via the monitor."- what makes you think that the monitor, (which has no USB-C), is capable of charging your laptop?